# How to go about creating homotopies?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to create a homotopy between the paths
$$I \to S^{1} \quad \text{by} \quad t \mapsto e^{i \pi + 2 i \pi t} $$
and
$$ I \to S^{1} \quad \text{by} \quad
t \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
e^{i \pi (1-4t)}, & t \in [0, \frac{1}{4}]\\
e^{i \pi (8t - 2)}, & t \in [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}]\\
e^{i \pi (2t-1)},& t \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]
\end{cases}. $$

I'm having a bit of trouble getting all of the components to fit in, but visually, I think what one wants is to make the second path run through $[0, \frac{3}{8}]$ in less and less time until it becomes that it doesn't run through that part at all. Then runs through
$[\frac{3}{8}, \frac{1}{2}]$ in eventually $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, and the rest runs through in the same time. If that makes sense...

Could anyone help me along in understanding how to create this type of mapping?

Edit: Woops, I forgot the 2 in $i \pi + 2 i \pi t$ in the first path's expression. Thanks for pointing it out @Martin Brandenburg

Comment: As a side note, it is worth learning how the difference in meaning between $\to$ and $\mapsto$. I fixed your usage here.

Comment: The endpoints are not the same, so there cannot be a homotopy. I assume you just have a typo?

Comment: Well there could be a homotopy, not rel endpoints. But in this case there really is no homotopy -- the former path is nullhomotopic and the latter path is not.

Comment: When we talk about homotopy of paths, it is with respect to endpoints, right? Otherwise we just speak of homotopy of the underlying continuous functions.

Comment: That's a very reasonable convention! Not my standard but I understand where you're coming from. Anyway, doesn't end up mattering here. Edit: I am wrong, it matters if we do this rel endpoints or not! Apologies

Comment: Sorry, indeed it was a typo. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your two functions $f(t)=e^{i\pi \alpha(t)}$ and $g(t)=e^{i\pi\beta(t)}$.

If you graph $\alpha,\beta$ in the plane, the first is a line segment, the second is three line segments. Notice the third line segment of $\beta$ differs from $\alpha$ by $2\pi$ $-$ thus, we can replace the third formula for $\beta(t)$ with $2t+1$ instead of $2t-1$, without changing the function $g(t)$. Now $\alpha,\beta$ match on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

It remains to homotope $\beta$ to $\alpha$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Note the graph of $\beta$ is made up of two line segments, first from $(0,1)$ to $(\frac{1}{4},0)$ and then from $(\frac{1}{4},0)$ to $(\frac{1}{2},2)$; just "pull" the middle point up until the two line segments become the same, i.e. that of $\alpha$! Do you see how this can be done with formulas?